# Get class from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to get the class i added to JPanel and run a function within the class.
I created `MyButton` class that extends `JButton`, This class i added to JPanel but after i added this class i want to run `getText()` on this objects.
I tried this but it does not recognize the function:

```
 panel.getComponent(1).getText();
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      
            panel.add(new MyButton());
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

**MyButton**

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
private String text;

public MyButton()
{
    this.text="Hello";

    setText("test");
}
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java get JPanel Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370310/java-get-jpanel-components)

Comment: (1-) You were asked for an [mre] in your last question. As soon as you posted one you got your answer. Where is your "MRE". Every question should have an "MRE". We don't know the context of your code we have no idea why or where you actually invoke `panel.getComponent(1).getText();`. A question should be complete with the "MRE" so we can understand the context. Also, why are you creating a custom class. The JButton already has a `setText(…)` method. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Looks like you haven't casted before calling your custom method.

String text = ((MyButton) panel.getComponent(1)).getText();

Comment: `MyButton extends JButton` I have yet to see a good reason to extend a button. What is yours? Agree with @camickr re MRE. I won't give most questions serious consideration until the code is compiled in my editor.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, surprised you wrote an MRE for the OP. Not only has the OP not listened to suggestions to post an MRE with every question, the OP completely ignored the answer you provided in his last question by still using both row/column parameters when creating the GridLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel.getComponent(1).getText();
```

This returns a `Component`, which has no `getText()` method. It needs to be cast back to a `JButton` in order to use that method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 5));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                panel.add(new JButton("Text " + (i+1)));
            }
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
            for (Component component : components) {
                JButton b = (JButton) component;
                System.out.println(b.getText());
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

BTW - having to trawl back though a panel to get the components seems like a poor hack. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Whatever the actual goal is here (& what is that goal?) is likely better served by storing the buttons in an array or list structure, when created.